# Currently testing file name in pytest

Tags: pytest

I am new to Pytest and I am trying to give parameters for the test functions dynamically based on the file in which the function is present. please let me know how to find the file path of the currently testing file path.

Comment: @FrankAK No,this will give the file path of the Conftest.py file in pytest but I need the path of the file which is being tested.

Comment: So, what's your project's structure look like? Can you describe it here?